# Conditional probability of the intersection of independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've found the following exercise:

> Suppose $A$,$B$ and $C$ are independent events and $P(A\cap B) \ne 0$. Show $P(C |A\cap B) = P(C)$

I've tried several times with no success and I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$\Pr(C|A\cap B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)}{\Pr(A\cap B)}.$$
By independence $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is almost the same as the one by Andre, but perhaps the following fact would be useful for you.

> If $A,B,C$ are mutually independent then $C\perp A\cap B$. Indeed:
>   $$
>   P(C\cap (A\cap B))  =P(C\cap A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)P(C) = P(C)P(A\cap B).
> $$

Now, if $F\perp G$ then $P(F|G) = P(F)$, so that choose $F=C$ and $G = A\cap B$ which gives you
$$
  P(C|A\cap B) = P(C),.
$$

Comment: I've not seen $\perp$ used before in this context, but I like it.  Am assuming it denotes independence, is that right?  Do you know of any probability references that use it?

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: Yes, this means independence. I do remember using it back in Russia, however I am not sure I can recall precisely whether I saw such notation in English books on probability. I've seen in Kallenberg's Foundations they use of a similar symbol for conditional independence though.