# Does $A,B$ and $A,C$ independent imply also $A, B\cap C$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given three events $A, B$ and $C$. $A$ and $B$ are independent, $A$ and $C$ are also independent. How to prove following:

1. $P(A\mid B,C) = P(A)$ and
2. $P(B\cap C\mid A) = P(B\cap C)$.

From intuition, this is true, as the joint of $B$ and $C$, should be independent of $A$. Just wondering how to prove this by probability logic.

Comment: With $B,C$ you mean actually $B\cap C$?

Comment: Yes, B,C means B∩C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove it, because it does not hold. Consider two independent coin tosses, (with possible outcomes $h$ and $t$) and let

1. $A=\{ht,th\}$,
2. $B=\{ht,tt\}$,
3. $C=\{ht,hh\}$.

It is immediate to prove that $A,B$ and $A,C$ are independent, but $$P(A\mid B\cap C)=P(A\mid ht)=1\neq \frac12=P(A)$$

Comment: I am confused with the difference of this one. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415639/conditional-probability-of-the-intersection-of-independent-events?rq=1
What does A, B, and C all independent imply? If A, B and C all independent with each other, then P(B, C) = P(B)P(C), but does it ensure P(A, B, C) = P(A)P(B)P(C), as your example, A, B and C are independent, but A is not independent of B joint C.

Comment: If $A,B,C$ all independent (or correcly mutually independent), then yes, $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$. This implies the weaker $A,B,C$ are pairwise independent as it is here. But pairwise independent does not imply mutual independence hence no confusion.